# how to make the div hidden without flicker using ng-hide

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-hide

Am using ng-hide to hide a div. it display when dom loaded and hides after a milli second.

```
 <div class="container" ng-hide = "{{flag}}">
```

how to make the div hidden without flicker

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-if` - in this case if the result of your condition is `false` then there wouldn't be a `div` element at all in the DOM.

`ng-hide` uses CSS (afaik) to hide the specific element but the element is still put inside the DOM. The CSS is applied after the DOM rendering - that is why you see this "flickering"

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" ng-hide="{{flag}}" ng-cloak>
```

hide by default until your DOM has been compiled

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `ng-show="{{flag}}"` it will show div according to flag, if flag is false it won't show div else it will show.